# How many Rows can an SQL Data Table hold

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently working on a point of sales software in which I have a table to record each and every item of a transaction, Since its going to hold hundreds of records each day after its release, I just wanna know the maximum amount of records that can be held by a Table and can anyone pls let me know whether it can slow down the software over time.

Comment: Hundreds of records a day? So if it's used for 100 years it will have about 36.5 million records in (999 records being the last reasonable value one could say is in the "hundreds"). Why don't you knock up a quick query to insert 36,500,000 records into your table and see if the whole thing dies in a heap? It'll be more sure than asking us to make promises we can't keep (especially as we don't know what database you're even using), though I doubt it will. Unless you're doing it on very low spec machine

Comment: `I just wanna know the maximum amount of records` Lots more than you are creating. I've worked on systems that generate that many records _per day_. `pls let me know whether it can slow down the software over time.` Yes it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For practical day-to-day purposes (where you're inserting hundreds or thousands of rows per day) there is no limit to the size of the table, except if it fills up your disk.

Remember that organisations with userbases larger than yours, use databases with not hundreds of rows per day, but millions of rows per day.

Typically though, you will start to run into performance issues that needs fixing. You can still get good performance, you just need to do more to watch and tweak it.

For example, you may have a typical table with, say,

- An ID (autoincrement/identity) that is the Primary Key (and clustered index).
- A date/time field recording when it occurred
- Some other data e.g., user IDs, amounts, types of action, etc

Each row you insert into the table just puts a new row at the end of that table, which databases typically have no problem doing. Even if the table is already large, adding more rows isn't much of a problem.

However, imagine you have a query/report that gets the data for the last week - for example, `SELECT * FROM trn_log WHERE trn_datetime >= DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())`

At first that runs fine.

After a while, it slows down. Why? Because the database doesn't know the that the datetimes are sequential, and therefore it must read every row of the table and work out which of the rows are the ones you want to use.

At that point, you start to think about indexes - which is a good next step. But when you add an index, it slows down your new row inserts (by a small amount).

I learned a lot from watching Brent Ozar's videos. I recommend watching his [How to Think Like the SQL Server Engine series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDYqU5RH_aX1VSVvjdla9TOKf939UhIDB).

Note that this above is based on my experience with SQL Server - but it's likely (at this fundamental level) most other databases are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows per page is limited to 255 rows so that works out to 4.1 billion rows per partition. A table can have an unlimited number of partitions and a single server can manage up to 128PB of storage.
[https://www.quora.com/How-many-rows-can-recent-SQL-and-NoSQL-databases-reasonably-handle-within-one-table#:~:text=The%20number%20of%20rows%20per,up%20to%20128PB%20of%20storage](https://www.quora.com/How-many-rows-can-recent-SQL-and-NoSQL-databases-reasonably-handle-within-one-table#:%7E:text=The%20number%20of%20rows%20per,up%20to%20128PB%20of%20storage).

Comment: You forgot to answer the "will it slow down" question 

Comment: The answer to will it slow down over time will be yes, but this can be mitigated by reindexing maintenance plans, moving records into history tables, etc

Comment: Really? You have to move data out of tables to keep it performant? How did you know it was SQL server?